# Sculpt Brushes Not Accurate

Tags: mesh, baking, sculpting, normal-map

I'm having a strange problem when sculpting a relatively high poly mesh (500K vertices or so). The sculpting brushes seem to work as expected for the most part. However, every-so-often the brushes will apply sculpting changes in the wrong places on my mesh.

For example, if I'm aiming the pointer at one part of my mesh, the smoothing brush may apply the sculpting far above or below my mouse pointer, while nothing happens within the radius of the smoothing brush outline.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a fix? I have just been restarting blender and that seems to work half of the time.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't say I faced something like that or really imagine what the problem is, but try switching viewport to orthographic mode (Numpad 5).